# Is there a way to loop through posts with specific tags on Siteleaf using liquid template?

Tags: for-loop, liquid

Here's the scenario: I have a portfolio website running on Siteleaf (siteleaf.com - which uses liquid template) and I have a portfolio section with several projects as posts. The trick is that I only wish to bring the projects with the tag **featured**

I was able to bring the posts but only limit the number of posts that is shown, but not the tag that they are assigned. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<ul class="container work-gallery clearfix">
  {% for post in site.pages['work'].posts limit:6 %}
    <li class="col-md-6 thumb">
      <a href="{{post.url}}" style="background-image: url('{{post.assets.first.url}}');">
        <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet you've since figured this out, because you're super close.

There are a few ways to do this (more info [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) and [here](http://www.siteleaf.com/help/themes/variables/taxonomy-and-tags/)). I'll assume for this example that you're using Siteleaf's default `tags` taxonomy (aka Tag Set).

```
<ul>
{% for post in taxonomy['tags']['featured'].posts limit:6 %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{post.url}}">
      <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You could then just add an `if` if you wanted to do something with the others.

Alternatively, if you wanted to really party, you could use the `assign` tag to store a variable, then use it as a condition for output (or for additional `tags` or variables).

```
{% assign featured_posts = '' %}

<ul>
{% for post in taxonomy['tags']['featured'].posts limit:6 %}
  {% assign featured_posts = featured_posts | append:',' | append:post.id %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{post.url}}">
      <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}

...

<ul> 
{% for post in posts %}

{% unless featured_posts contains post.id %}
  <li class="not-featured">
    <a href="{{post.url}}">
      <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
    </a> 
  </li>
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```